# How to write multiline text to textarea in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel. In one of my forms, I store the text of the textarea in the database.

```
{!! Form::textarea('mline', isset($mline) ? strip_tags($mline) : null, ['style'=>'height: 113px;width:150%;','class'=>'p-2']) !!}
```

If the text inside the textarea is multiple lines, each line is stored in the database with the `<p>` tag at the beginning and end of the line. As below:

```
<p>line 1</p><p>line 2</p>
```

In the edit form, when reading from the database and writing to the textarea as it is stored in the database, the text is displayed with the `<p>` tag.

While I want the text to be displayed in the original format and the lines below it without the `<p>` tag.

I also used the strip_tags($string) function, but it only removes the `<p>` tags and the lines are displayed consecutively and stuck together.

How can I display lines in html format without displaying tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `nl2br()` function can convert newline characters to `<br>` tags. This will preserve the line breaks when displaying the text in HTML. You can further modify the code to remove any trailing `<br />` tags from each line. This can be done by using the `rtrim()` function in PHP, which removes specified characters from the end of a string.

```php
{!! Form::textarea('mline', isset($mline) ? rtrim(str_replace('<br />', "\n", nl2br(strip_tags($mline))), "\n") : null, ['style'=>'height: 113px;width:150%;','class'=>'p-2']) !!}
```

Here, `rtrim(..., "\n")` removes any trailing newline characters from the text. This will ensure no extra line breaks at the end of the text.

Comment: It was fixed to some extent, but the <br /> tag is displayed at the end of the lines